# Rest Service URL for jbpm7.36

Tags: jbpm

What is the URL to be used for accessing JBPM V 7.36 is it **http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console** or **http://localhost:8080/kie-server**?

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

- If you downloaded Business Central, KIE Server and WildFly individually from https://www.drools.org/download/download.html then they will be available at `:8080/[name-of-war-file-deployed]`.
- If you downloaded the jBPM single zip distribution from https://www.jbpm.org/download/download.html, you get Business Central at `:8080/business-central`, the KIE server at `:8080/kie-server` and the jBPM Case Management application at `:8080/jbpm-casemgmt` (an example app)